# Using tags to select group of pictures in gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to create gallery. I have buttons: all, mobile, desktop, shop etc. Pictures are located on server and has assigned tags. For example one picture tags: all, mobile, shop. How to assign tags in html ? To the class, data attributes or another way ? After press button I'd like to show only one type pictures for example with mobile tag.

Comment: Using classes or data attributes would both work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you already have your pictures generated in html page, you can use something like `<img data-tag="mobile-desktop" src="link" />` to make the image tag be mobile and desktop. based on the click, using javascipt, you simply filter images whose data-tag attribute contains the tag you want. If you need further the, tell it in comment

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use css classes, you can use custom data attributes in the `HTML`

`<img data-tag='mobile' ... >`

And a selector

`$('img[data-tag=mobile]')`

Answer (score -1):

You can set data directly in html tag like so data-name = "value". There is also the option to store the element in a variable using jquery or JavaScript and doing variableName.attr(data, value). You can also create variables in javascript, assign it a value then select classname and do .data(value)